# Eclipse export as executable jar NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

My project runs just fine in eclipse but exporting as executable jar leads to a bunch of problems. The .jar is not executable, doubleclicking does nothing. Running java -jar on the .jar in cmd gives a lot of NPE, apparently the scanner when ran from the .jar is null. The getResource returns null and I do not know why.

```
Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader(getClass().getResource(filename)
                .getFile()));
        readLine(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where `filename = "../001.txt"`

The class that runs the scanner is in `game/`. The file `001.txt` is `levels/` so the `../001.txt` SHOULD work.

This is what the manifest looks like inside the .jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: game.Game
```

This is a very annoying problem and googling for hours provided no solution, I had a similar problem before but that was with actually loading relative paths and not NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getResource() loads resources from the classpath, not from a filesystem path. So if the 001.txt is in the package levels, you should put:

filename = "/levels/001.txt";

the leading "/" is for absolute path. If you put "../001.txt" this is a relative classpath and is transformed in /levels/game/../001.txt